# V5.0.3 Click simulation

Tags: openlayers-5

I cannot create a new Click Event since ol V5 (example to simulate a click on a feature) :

```
var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinates);
var evt = new ol.MapEvent();
evt.type = ol.MapBrowserEventType.CLICK;
evt.pixel = pixel;
map.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Error :

```
ol.MapEvent is not a constructor
```

I use the full build ol.js.

It works by using a jQuery event ...

```
var evt = jQuery.Event( "click", { target: sMap.olMap.getTargetElement(), pixel: pixel, pageX: pixel[0], pageY: pixel[1] } );
```

Why we cannot instanciate MapEvent or MapBrowserEvent anymore ?
Or what is the good way to do that ?

Thx